# 2,3-Flows on 4-edge-connected graphs

Tags: graph-theory, flows

I just stumbled across the following question concerning special Nowhere-Zero-Flows on 4-edge-connected graphs:

Does every 4-edge-connected graph admit a flow (on some and thus all orientations) ranging in $\{\pm 2, \pm 3\}$?

I know that Tutte's 3-Flow-Conjecture proposes a very similar result with values $\{\pm 1,\pm 2\}$ required instead, but I do not yet see a simple reduction in neither direction.

I would be grateful for any kind of help concerning e.g. counterexamples, reductions, helpful links to existing results or even a proof of the statement.

Best